# Who wrote the theme music for the 1970s UK TV drama "A Bouquet of Barbed Wire"?

Tags: unknown-composer

Who wrote the theme music for the 1970s UK TV drama **A Bouquet of Barbed Wire**?

I have a gorgeous version of it on cassette but I've lost the label so I don't know any of the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme music for the 1976 production was written by the Canadian composer [Dennis Farnon](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0267879/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm) (1923-2019).

Comment: Google is very good for finding information like this.

Comment: I should have scrolled down the results page a bit more…